# Dynamic SQL and Bulk Insert

Tags: oracle, oracle11g

I want to use the execute immediate command, to insert collection below PROCEDURE

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE P_LOAD_HLD(
    p_app_name     IN VARCHAR2,
    p_filename     IN VARCHAR2,
    p_rectype     IN VARCHAR2,
    p_tabname     IN VARCHAR2,
    o_status     OUT Number)
   IS

    type t_tab is table of  holding_template%rowtype;
    v_tab     t_tab;
    process_size    number := 10000; 
    dummy_cursor     SYS_REFCURSOR;

   BEGIN
    o_status := 0;
    null;

    if p_rectype='my_test' THEN         
       OPEN dummy_cursor FOR
         select  *      
         from  TAB_staging a
         where a.record_type =  p_filename;    

    end if;

    LOOP 

      BEGIN   
       FETCH dummy_cursor BULK COLLECT INTO V_TAB LIMIT PROCESS_SIZE;
       FORALL I IN V_TAB.FIRST .. V_TAB.LAST
       execute immediate 'insert into '||p_tabname||' values v_tab(i))'; 
       EXCEPTION WHEN OTHERS THEN      
         FOR I IN 1 .. V_TAB.COUNT 
           LOOP
           BEGIN 
           EXECUTE IMMEDIATE ' INSERT INTO '||p_tabname || ' VALUES  ( '||                                                             
                                  'v_tab(i).k0,v_tab(i).k1,v_tab(i).k2,v_tab(i).k3,v_tab(i).k4';
           COMMIT; 
           EXCEPTION WHEN OTHERS THEN 
           RAISE;                                  
           END;           
           END LOOP; 

      END;     

    END LOOP;   

   END P_LOAD_HLD ;
```

this gives me the error message.

> [Error] PLS-00435 (742: 7): PLS-00435: DML statement without BULK
>   In-BIND cannot be used inside FORALL

Comment: Just to check the `execute immedate` in your code here is spelled properly in your actual program, correct?

Comment: Yes spelling is not an issue here